# Are there any option/chance in this website in which I can write everything to have corrected?

Tags: feature-request

My writing skill in English is very weak. I often write sentences that sometimes include wrong words, therefore sound unnatural, awkward, or they are grammatically wrong. I found that this website is very helpful in learning English. Everyday I want to write something in English in this website to have corrected. When I will know what are the correct forms of my written sentences, I will be able to improve my skill ness. Are there any option/chance in this site in which I can write something to have corrected? If there are, please tell how to submit ones writing.

Comment: This is not a proofreading site. I wish there were one, but I just don't know of one. Google for 'english proofreading site'

Comment: @Mitch - what about arrowfar and ice girl? Is that not an option?

Comment: @medica- please say more about arrowfar and ice girl? What is it? What are the functions of it?

Comment: @NazmulHassan - Mitch is quite correct that this is not a proofreading site. There is a site here ([English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)) for prople learning English, which (while also not a proofreading service), you might find more amenable to developing friendships where you could practice your English in a chat room, private or public. That's what I was referring to. That has occasionally happened on this site as well.

Comment: @medica I don't think arrowfar or ice girl would be interested in proofreading. Arrowfar is a native (or very fluent) speaker and Ice Girl is a learner. If you are referring to chat, that is a very informal resource for once in a while proofreading questions, but not systematic as Nazmul is requesting. We would be happy to check things once in a while but chat is not a dedicated proofreading service and to treat it as such would be frustrating for everybody/

Comment: @Mitch - You misunderstand. Ice Girl found someone interested in helping her to improve her English. Arrowfar used chat to do that. While I don't think chat is the way to improve your English (it is very tedious), the OP is asking if there is a possibility of improving their English here. There ought to be a more comprehensive answer than "No." He asked so politely. To me, that's a refreshing change from many meta questions.

Answer (score 4):

General proofreading requests are [explicitly not acceptable](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, as a longstanding community guideline; see *[Can I ask the community to help me find errors in a text/sentence?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383/can-i-ask-the-community-to-help-me-find-errors-in-a-text-sentence)* and *[Does this sort of question qualify as proofreading?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/512/does-this-sort-of-question-qualify-as-proofreading)*, and also *[How about allowing people to post entire compositions?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327)*.

Moreover, general proofreading requests are not accepted at the [English Language Learners SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), nor at [Writers SE](https://writers.stackexchange.com/). I would not expect them to be accepted anywhere on StackExchange, as it is ill-suited to a format where only one answer is can be deemed the best, and you can only vote on an entire answer, and not components of an answer.

Good proofreading is time-consuming, and what is "good" or "correct" or "polite" and so on is dependent on many factors, from the type of communication to the global locale to the tone of the message. A great deal of context is required. As such, a good proofreading request would be too specific to be of much help to any future visitors, and even then subject to opinion, or require too lengthy a response to be suitable. The proofreading requests we do see, by and large, are not good ones.

Others have suggested finding a language partner through any of a number of other sites, for example

- [lang-8.com](http://lang-8.com/)
- [Livemocha](http://livemocha.com/)
- [italki](https://www.italki.com/)